# How to prevent click events from overlapping each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please see image below for error:

As shown, there is conflicting text. The initial state of the website has 6 blocks with different colors with text in the center. When clicked on, more information is displayed in the middle section. However, when you click on another box the background color is changed and/or the text inside each box is either shown or hidden.

I suspect this is happening due to my incorrect use of jQuery

Comment: It's a bit a mess but I try to explain: If you toggle the first time, every box gets colored the same, but they are not one element - so if you click on the closing X (or on another same colored item - but another item in general) the color gets changed becuase the click handler registers a click on this "field" - because there are still 6 fields but only with the same color if you click on one.

Comment: To quick fix that, you have to block the other elements, but in general you would need a better architecture for such an design. I can provide an fix for that.

Comment: Any fixes you can provide would be welcome as this is stressing me out. It's 2am here where I am and I'm still banging my head against the wall trying to fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to fixed it hands on but still doesn't work that well because you have to click on the field with which you opened the field to close it again. you should build a click handler for the closing icon, then it should work.

https://codepen.io/felixhaeberle/pen/qGjpVJ

First, I check each Item if it is blocked and if it's blocked, return.
Then I set all items to blocked and after unblock the current (this) item.
A closing click handler (close icon) should remove all blocked entry's like `$('.closing-link').click(function(){ allItems.toggleClass("blocked"); // your closing code follows here });`

```
  $("#fbPageDesign").on('click', function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("blocked")) return;
    allItems.toggleClass('blocked');
    $(this).toggleClass("blocked");
    $(".box").toggleClass("bg-color2");
    $(".boxText,.whiteRectangle").toggle();
  });
```

a snippet out of my solution.